# django model permission vs group permissions

Tags: python, django, django-admin

My django model looks like this:

```
class testModel(models.Model):
    ...
    def has_add_permission(self, request):
        return False
    ...
```

My group permission looks like this:

```
employee: testApp | testModel | can add testModel
```

The user can still add objects:

[image]

It look like the the `has_add_permission` function is being ignored as the button only disappears when the permission is removed from the group;

group permission: can add testModel and has_add_permission returns true

- Result: Can add test model

group permission: can add testModel and has_add_permission returns false

- Result: Can add test model

group permission: cannot add testModel and has_add_permission returns true

- Result: cannot add test model

group permission: cannot add testModel and has_add_permission returns false

- Result: cannot add test model

Is this expected behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

If you are referring to [this part](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.has_add_permission) of the docs, you should know that there they are talking about the `ModelAdmin` methods, not the model directly.

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ...

    def has_add_permission(self, request):
        return False
```

I don't think it is supposed to work by defining those methods directly on the models, you will have to define them in the admin class of that model.